# PyQt5 run Multithreaded processes consicutively on single thread

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am working on an application in PyQT5 which has two docks on either side and an OCC 3d viewer and a TextEdit in the middle. The .ExportToImage() method of the OCC viewer allows taking a screenshot of the viewer. But since the Application has a responsive design, the Viewer is resized to be thin(on certain display resolutions) and thus the screenshot also comes out to be thin.

[image: GUI]

[image: Screenshot of 3d Viewer for small resolutions]

I've tried to resize the window to a particular size and then hide everything except the 3D viewer. This enlarges the viewer thus saving from a cropped screenshot. But when I hide and resize and then take the screenshot, the screenshot still comes out to be thin. Here's the code:

```
def take_screenshot(self):
 Ww=self.frameGeometry().width()                   
 Wh=self.frameGeometry().height()
 self.resize(700,500)
 self.outputDock.hide() #Dock on the right
 self.inputDock.hide()  #Dock on the left
 self.textEdit.hide()   #TextEdit on the Bottom-Middle
 self.display.ExportToImage(fName)   #Display is the 3d Viewer's display on the Top-Middle
 self.resize(Ww,Wh)
 self.outputDock.show()
 self.inputDock.show()
 self.textEdit.show()
```

I guess this happens because the above .show(), .hide(), .resize() methods of PyQt5 are multithreaded and as soon as I run them they dont run consicutively but parallely. Thus the screenshot is taken before the other processes complete.

Is there a way to resolve this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no multiple threads. events are processed in loops, so called eventloop.

try this:

```
def take_screenshot(self):
    Ww=self.frameGeometry().width()                   
    Wh=self.frameGeometry().height()
    self.resize(700,500)
    self.outputDock.hide() #Dock on the right
    self.inputDock.hide()  #Dock on the left
    self.textEdit.hide()   #TextEdit on the Bottom-Middle
    QTimer.singleShot(0, self._capture)

def _capture(self):
    # app.processEvents()  # open this line if it still doesn't work, I don't know why.
    self.display.ExportToImage(fName)   #Display is the 3d Viewer's display on the Top-Middle
    self.resize(Ww,Wh)
    self.outputDock.show()
    self.inputDock.show()
    self.textEdit.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, The QTimer does exactly what I wanted to do. Also, thanks for the explanation above.